# wicket textarea in listview is cleared when unset the ajaxcheckbox

Tags: java, listview, wicket

I created one checkbox and one textfield for each line using wicket listview.

When the user selects the checkbox I am able to set the related boolean value 
succesfully.

But I needed to put a restriction. Only one checkbox can be 
selected to submit the form in the following structure.

> Textarea checkbox 
>   Textarea checkbox 
>   Textarea checkbox 
>   Textarea checkbox

The text that I typed into the textareas are removed when I unset the checkbox that I selected. 
As far as I know the following line is used to prevent this problem but it doesnt work. Do you have any idea?

```
listView.setReuseItems(true);
```

```
public class CheckBoxListPage extends WebPage {      
    private Form inputForm; 

    public CheckBoxListPage() 
    { 
            add(inputForm = new InputForm("inputForm")); 
    } 

    private class InputForm extends Form 
    {  
            private List<NameWrapper> data; 

            public InputForm(String name) 
            { 
                    super(name);                    
                    data = new ArrayList<NameWrapper>(); 
                    data.add(new NameWrapper("one")); 
                    data.add(new NameWrapper("two")); 
                    data.add(new NameWrapper("three")); 
                    data.add(new NameWrapper("four")); 

                    final ListView<NameWrapper> listView = new ListView<NameWrapper>("list", data) 
                    { 
                            protected void populateItem(ListItem<NameWrapper> item) { 
                                    final NameWrapper wrapper = (NameWrapper)item.getModelObject(); 
                                    item.add(new Label("name", wrapper.getName())); 
                                    final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox("check", new PropertyModel<Boolean>(wrapper, "selected")); 
                                    item.add(checkBox); 
                                    checkBox.add(new OnChangeAjaxBehavior() { 
                                            @Override 
                                            protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {                                                                                                   
                                                    if (wrapper.getSelected()) { 
                                                            for (NameWrapper entity : data) { 
                                                                    if (!entity.equals(wrapper)) { 
                                                                            entity.setSelected(Boolean.FALSE); 
                                                                    } 
                                                            } 
                                                    } 
                                                    target.addComponent(inputForm); 
                                            }                                              
                                    }); 
                            } 
                    }; 
                listView.setReuseItems(true); 
                add(listView); 
            }             
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful if you included in the code how are you building those textareas, and if you're adding them back to the `AjaxRequestTarget`.

Anyway, I see you're trying to implement a server-side behavior to make something you could do client-side (actually, it's a client-side operation). You'd be far better unchecking all other checkboxes client-side, for instance, with javascript.

You can make your `Component` implement `IHeaderContributor`, and output the checkboxes' HTML `id` attributes to Javascript. Then, every checkbox can have an `onchange` event handler in which you can uncheck all other checkboxes selecting them with `document.getElementById()`.

With this approach, you wouldn't need `setReuseItems(true)`. In case you write the `ListView` back to the `AjaxRequestTarget`, `setReuseItems()` would help you keep the same `Components` that were instantiated in the first execution of `populateItem()` (i.e, they would keep the same markupId's). In general, if you need to manage state of components inside the `ListView`, it's recommendable to use `setReuseItems(true)`. In this case this is done client-side, so it's not necessary at first glance.

For instance:

```
private class InputForm extends Form implements IHeaderContributor {

    private List<String> checkboxIds = new ArrayList();
    //...
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<NameWrapper> item) { 
            // PropertyModel can be used on Models, too, 
            // not necessarily modelObejcts.
            IModel checkboxModel = new PropertyModel<Boolean>(item.getModel(), "selected"));
            final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox("check", checkboxModel);                                 
            checkBox.setOutputMarkupId(true);

            // If checkboxMarkupId is null at this point, 
            // you can always set it this way
            // checkBox.setMarkupId("check" + item.getIndex());

            String checkboxMarkupId = checkBox.getMarkupId();
            checkboxIds.add(checkboxMarkupId);            
            item.add(checkBox); 
            String js = "deselectChecks('" + checkboxMarkupId + "');";
            checkbox.add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("onchange", js));
        }
    //...
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
        String jsArrDecl = "var checkIds = [";
        for (String checkId : checkboxIds){
            jsArrDecl += "'" + checkId + "', ";
        }
        jsArrDecl = jsArrDecl.substring(0, jsArrDecl.length()-1);
        jsArrDecl += "];";
        response.renderOnDomReadyJavascript(jsArrDecl);
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
function deselectChecks(selected){
     for each (var checkId in checkIds) {
          if (checkId != selected){
              document.getElementById(checkId).checked = false;
          }
     }
}
```

You can append `onchange="deselectChecks(this.id);"` to the checkboxes in the HTML file, or add it with a `SimpleAttributeModifier` in the Java class.

As always, you should also implement this restriction/behavior server-side to prevent users without javascript to bypass it. I'd suggest a `FormValidator` to that effect.